# C# to C++ multithreading, any issues to expect?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, performance, pinvoke

After a lot of testing i have a dozen algorithms that don't give me satisfactory speed in C# and that work just fine in C++ (implemented the same way, pretty much copy pasted from C# to C++, heavily array based on large data sets).

Now i know how to call C++ code from C# and i don't want to switch the whole application over, so i'm thinking of doing that. However those micro kernels must run heavily in parallel and since parallelism in .net is really nice, i was thinking of handling it on that side, and having each thread from C# call whatever is relevant.

It sounds to me like i shouldn't have any issues with thread safety that way (i'm not calling any C++ lib functionality, all the methods are just taking arrays as input and returning arrays as output, data is not shared accross threads on either the C++ or C# side). But since i've never had to do that my question is : Is it completely stupid? Am i missing a huge elephant in the room or should i be fine? Do i have to worry about wether i use the MT runtime on the C++ side or not considering i don't call in any of the system calls?

Each microkernel is slow enough (100+ms) for the .net boundary cross not to be a big issue and substantially faster in C++ but i'd rather avoid porting all my code and testing to realise i missed something obvious.

Comment: Is there even a single threaded runtime these days?

Comment: No clue i saw diferent runtimes in options last i checked, but my question wasn't specifically about that, i don't normally do C++ and wanted to make sure nothing special had to be done for it to be used in that fashion (to avoid bad surprises like "oh you didn't know marshalling to a C++ lib isn't thread safe?" after a lot of proting work, fake example obviously but since i don't have the knowledge, i'd rather ask than waste days)

Comment: Well, you did mention that issue. But you should have no problems with calling pinvokes from different threads as you describe. I think I'd use C++/CLI though.

Comment: Wouldn't that be just adding a third layer? Sounds like more work

Comment: The interop is liable to be more efficient, as a general rule. And why would that be a third layer. Compile the C++ code into a C++/CLI module.

Comment: Ah you mean write the algorithm in C++/CLI directly? Don't think i can do that (is the module mixed managed / unmanaged or is it all managed code including the C++? If the later i doubt the compiler will do a lot better than C# and in either case it won't allow me to use the intel C++ compiler which adds a lot more performance i may as well take if going to C++)

Comment: I had in mind a mixed mode C++/CLI module, so the microkernel is still unmanaged code.

Comment: How would that work? Is the unmanaged side compiled separately (so possibly with intel C++) and then merged in the module or does it have to be done in one step?

Comment: No. I think the unmanaged part has to be MS compiler. Unless you link in a static lib compiled by Intel.

Comment: In that case it sounds like quite a bit of work vs the P/Invoke, also it's not a chatty interface anyway so it doesn't sound like it's Worth going the intel C++ => static lib => import in C++/CLI => use from C# road

Comment: You might want to provide some code samples that we can look at

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are safe to do it that way but marshalling accross the C++/C# divide has some overhead.

some thoughts:

Consider using C++ CLI

If your algorithm is data parallel consider using the GPU either via a managed library or using CUDA via C++  (there are managed wrappers)

I have not used the RyuJIT (the new jit compiler) in .net yet, but it is also capable of using the SIMD instructions that may prove useful without having to go C++.

Comment: My algorithms aren't SIMD able (i can't take 4 or 8 elements of the array in sequence and apply the same process to each), also GPGPU is out of the question due to the size of the data sets i'm working with (target hardware is 160 thread / 2TB server). In my tests the C++ compiler is giving me massively better results for array read/writes as soon as i'm not reading in sequencial fashion hence the reason for the switch (some of the algorithms run at 4X the speed).

Comment: And i'm already targeting .net 4.6 and thus using ryujit, performance is still too slow :(

Comment: At that data volume it may well be then that the GC is too aggressive. C++ may indeed be the way to go (as you describe in the original question)

Comment: The GC doesn't seem to be the issue really, this happens even when testing on small tests in single threaded fashion (a few dozen MB then), it's also perfectly stable performance (unconsistent with GC spikes) and allocation free (arrays getting reused). It's just slower, somewhat slower than C++ on sequencial access, but massively slower on non sequencial access (even when targeting neighboors in array). No clue why really

Comment: Can you share any more information? I am somwhat curious ... you can also send me a pm (malionet at gmail)

Comment: can't really share much but emailing you now

Answer (score 3):

> not calling any C++ lib functionality, all the methods are just taking arrays as input and returning arrays as output, data is not shared accross threads on either the C++ or C# side

Since there is no sharing of data between the threads i think you are safe.

Comment: Aye it's fully shared-nothing, each thread has it's own set of arrays on the C# side, doesn't touch other thread's data, and will thus call in parallel  the C++ lib that also has no shared state, so potentially hundred of threads will call the same lib, but each passing their own data, getting their dedicated array back with nothing shared on either side